# Why is the following code showing run-time error(SIGSEGV)?

Tags: c

This is my solution to the Prime Generator problem on SPOJ(Sphere Online Judge)(http://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIME1/). I have allocated memory using malloc(), but it is still showing a run-time error(SIGSEGV).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    while(n--){
        int a,b;
        scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
        int *z =malloc(sizeof(int)*(b-1));
        // Filling the array
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<b-1;i++){
            z[i]=i+2;
        }

        int k,p;
        for(k=0;k<=b-2;k++){
            if(z[k]){
                if(z[k]>=a){
                    printf("%d\n", z[k]);
                }
                for(p=k+z[k];p<=b-2;p+=z[k]){
                    z[p]=0;
                }       
            }
        }
        free(z);    
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Usually, that means you are using memory you didn't allocate. `z[p]` and it's loop look like the culprit.

Comment: check return value of malloc.

Comment: Where does the segfault occur?  This is your opportunity to learn to use a debugger.  Also, what inputs trigger the problem?

Comment: Have you checked that b is > 1?

Comment: BTW your answer will be incorrect because you haven't read properly the condition *"test cases separated by an empty line"*.

Comment: "I have allocated memory using malloc". Yes, but you don't actually check whether `malloc` succeeded or not. SPOJ says the input `m` and `n` can be up to 1000000000. So your `malloc` can be up to about 4GB in size. There is no guarantee `malloc` can return you that much memory (though it might).

Comment: in C, an array index starts at 0 and continues until (number of elements in array -1)  This line: `z[i]=i+2;` is access z[i] when `i` is equal to `b-1`  However, only `b-1` elements were allocated in the call to malloc(), so this will access memory beyond the upper bound of the array.  Suggest changing the malloc to use `b` rather than `b-1`